# Facebook Graph API Explorer friends pagination, how to go to next page?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I search for my friends with the parameters

```
me/?fields=friends
```

It gives me a JSON with key `friends, and inside friends, data`. And then it has `paging` and inside it, `next`

```
{friends: {data:[], paging: {next:"a_monstrous_url"}}}
```

Only around 20 friends are returned. I tried setting a higher number in limit

```
me/?fields=friends.limit(200)
```

But still the same. Going to the link in json->pading->next, it gives me an empty array of friends.

How can I see the rest of my friends list

**@edit**

I just found out that Graph API is only returning information about the users who authorized the app to get information from them.

Answer (score 0):

`/me/friends` or `/me?fields?friends` only returns friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too, so it´s most likely correct not to get more.

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: it's not an APP. nobody has authorized it yet. i'm using the graph api to get information about myself

Comment: you MUST use an app for api calls. if you used the graph api explorer (i guess you mean that one with "graph api"), the default app is one from facebook called "Graph API Explorer" (see upper right corner of the api explorer, there is a dropdown). so that means, 20 of your friends have played with the api explorer.